# strip all scheme parts in a URL in php

Tags: php, string, url, replace

I want to fix this [vulnerability](https://talosintelligence.com/vulnerability_reports/TALOS-2020-1178), where the URL part of a PHP redirect is given by the query-string like

```
https://test.dev/test.php?return_page=contact.php
```

which will redirect to the other site `contact.php`.

An attacker could use this like:

```
https://test.dev/test.php?return_page=http://attack.hack
```

My idea is to strip double slashes in the function so the resulting redirect will be internal again and probably faulty:

```
$_GET['url']=str_replace("//","",$_GET['url']);
```

But maybe there is a better way to solve this with regex?

Comment: simply dont do `header('Location: '.$_GET['return_page'])`, if you fix the code which redirects to be like `header('Location: https://test.dev/' . $_GET['return_page'])` then  it would become `https://test.dev/http://attack.hack` which would be a 404

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? Stripping double slashes would simply generate an invalid URL

Comment: Are you planning on supporting path traversal in `return_page`, like `return_page=../path/file.php` or is it just a known set of files in a single folder?

Comment: I am not sure and don't have the time to dive deep into the phpGACL code. I just want to fix this issue https://talosintelligence.com/vulnerability_reports/TALOS-2020-1178

Comment: I understand you don't have time, but I also think you'll be doing yourself a disservice by trying to come up with a quick fix for this. That vulnerability category is common and old enough to have [half a dozen mitigation strategies](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html#Potential_Mitigations). Since that code hasn't been updated in 8 years, and the CVE is almost 2 years old, it doesn't seem too pressing, you could just log the various `return_path` items you find for a week or so, and then implement the first strategy with an error for anything not in the safe list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clean the URL of all possible scheme parts with

```
$url=preg_replace('/^([a-z0-9\s%;\+]+:\/\/+)+/i','',$_GET['url']);
header('Location: ' . $url)
```

i fixed that in https://github.com/rubo77/phpGACL

Comment: https://3v4l.org/gXmfJ

Comment: Please, please, please take note of @LawrenceCherone's POC for an exploit against this. This kind of code is actively in the wild right now. For reference, the OAuth spec is getting updated to basically acknowledge that it is unsafe to attempt URL parsing, too many things have gone wrong, and instead they demand that only exact string comparisons should be used.

Comment: Thx, I fixed the regex with an extra optional whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Have whitelist of allowed return-page parameters. If one is given which is it not allowed throw a 404 or forward to index.

```
$whitelist = ['contact.php', 'about.php'];

$returnPage = $_GET['return_page'] ?? '';

if (in_array($returnPage, $whitelist)) {
    header("Location: $returnPage");
    exit;
}

http_response_code(404)
exit;
```

If you anyways want to parse and verify the URL I recommend using [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url).

Comment: @rubo77 I did not know about phpGACL. But a redirection to a direct page which shows a readonly view could not do any damage. There are no parameters like deletion IDs.

Comment: The problem is, I didn't create phpGACL either and don't know which pages have to be redirected to keep the admin working. Please see my fork, where I fixed the issue like in my anser here at https://github.com/rubo77/phpGACL